# Vue.js - Automatic update of v-for not working with assigning new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I've been following this tutorial on vue3: Vue.js Tutorial: Beginner to Front-End Developer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GNsWa_EZdw&t=48s

Everything seems to be working on my side too, except the 'updating' of the nav list. He talks about the Eventlistener for the page update starting 04:01:20.

Why does assigning a new array to 'this.pages' not work to update the v-for on my side and what can I try/debug?

```js
this.$bus.$on('page-updated', () => {
    this.pages = [...this.$pages.getAllPages()];
});
```

Relevant script parts:

**Navbar.vue**

```
<template>
    ...
    <navbar-link
        v-for="(page, index) in publishedPages" 
        class="nav-item" 
        :key="index"
        :page="page"
        :index="index"                  
    ></navbar-link>
    ...
</template>

<script>
import NavbarLink from './NavbarLink.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        NavbarLink
    },
    inject: ['$pages', '$bus'],
    created() {
        this.pages = this.$pages.getAllPages();
        this.$bus.$on('page-updated', () => {
            this.pages = [...this.$pages.getAllPages()];
        });
    },
    data() {
        return {
            theme: 'dark',
            data: []
        }
    },
    computed: {
        publishedPages() {
            return this.pages.filter(p => p.published)
        }
    },
    ..
  } 
}
</script>
```

**PadeEdit.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { inject } from 'vue';
const router = useRouter();
const pages = inject('$pages');
const bus = inject('$bus');
const {index} = defineProps(['index']);
let page = pages.getSinglePage(index);
function submit() {
    pages.editPage(index, page);
    bus.$emit('page-updated', {
        index,
        page
    });
    ...
}
...
</script>
```

**Events.js**

```
const events = new Map();
export default {
    $on(eventName, fn) {
        if (!events.has(eventName)) {
            events.set(eventName, [])
        }
        events.get(eventName).push(fn);
    },
    $emit(eventName, data) {
        if (events.has(eventName)) {
            events.get(eventName).forEach(fn => fn(data));
        }
    }
};
```

**data.js**

```
const pagesKey = 'pages';

let pagesJson = localStorage.getItem(pagesKey);
let pagesStore = JSON.parse(pagesJson);

function save() {
    localStorage.setItem(pagesKey, JSON.stringify(pagesStore));
}

export default {
    addPage(page){
        pagesStore.push(page);
        save();
    },
    getAllPages() {
        return pagesStore;
    },
    getSinglePage(index) {
        return pagesStore[index];
    },
    editPage(index, page) {
        pagesStore[index] = page;
        save();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you upload all the code to a repo or online sandbox?  it's a lot of parts interacting together, and it would be easiest to debug a running example.  some of my questions include, does the `published` property get updated when editing?  does `editPage` update pagesStore as expected and does the `save` function update localStorage as expected?  what is the actual array value returned by `getAllPages`? etc.

Comment: Hi Philipp, can you make sure all files are uploaded to the github project?  The only Vue component right now is `App.vue`, and there are no `.js` files besides `main.js`.  Once the full project is uploaded I will take a look at it.  Thanks

Comment: @yoduh Sorry I missed some ... all the files should be available now. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Your Navbar.vue `data()` should be changed to:

```js
data() {
    return {
        theme: 'dark',
        pages: [], // <--- was previously data: []
        counter: 0
    }
},
```

#### Long answer:

After debugging the full Navbar.vue component, the issue is with the computed property referencing the wrong `this.pages`

```js
publishedPages() {
    return this.pages.filter(p => p.published);
}
```

The `this.pages` above is actually coming from the `created()` hook:

```js
created() {
    this.getThemeSetting();

    this.pages = this.$pages.getAllPages();          
    ...
}
```

But `this.pages` here is not a reactive variable.  When it updates, the computed property does not rerun.

This maybe raises the question, "why does it work initially?".

It's because computed properties run once on component creation to get their initial values, **and** you're literally defining `pages` on `this` with the statement `this.pages = ...`, so everything works ok during initialization. But because `this.pages` in the `created()` hook is not a reactive variable, `this.pages` is not being "watched" by Vue, so the computed property never runs again when `this.pages` updates. Only variables defined within `data()` are reactive.

The solution then is to add `pages` to `data()`

```js
data() {
    return {
        theme: 'dark',
        pages: [],  // <--- was originally "data: []"
        counter: 0
    }
},
```

Now, **any** reference to `this.pages` will be a reference to **this** reactive data variable. The rest of the code will now work. So when this runs:

```js
this.pages = [...this.$pages.getAllPages()];
```

It will update the `data` variable, and because `pages` is a **reactive** dependency of the computed property `publishedPages`, it will rerun itself. Finally, the v-for in the template will rerender because the computed property value has updated:

```html
<navbar-link v-for="(page, index) in publishedPages" />
```

P.S. this change from `data[]` to `pages[]` occurs in the tutorial video between [3:22:00](https://youtu.be/1GNsWa_EZdw?t=12124) and 3:22:30

He initially sets the data property as `data: []` but a few seconds later very quickly changes it to `pages: []`. It was probably very hard to notice while coding along

Comment: Thanks for looking into and spoting it! Also great answer and explanation! Best Regards